# Div element not floating to left

Tags: html, css

I wrote a responsive footer as shown in screen shot:
[image: img]
The text `HELP` and `back icon` aren't floating to left, but are struck in middle. How can I move it to left?
Here is the code:
**`HTML code`**:

```
<div id = "footer">

                <span id = "logout" class="pull-right">
                   <span id = "logoutIcon"></span>
                    <span id = "logoutText">
                        LOGOUT
                    </span>
                </span>

                <span id = "logout1" class="pull-right">
                   <span id = "logoutIcon1"></span>
                    <span id = "logoutText1">
                        HELP
                    </span>
                </span>

            </div>
```

**`CSS code:`**:

```
#footer {
            background-color: #125e9a;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 5%;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
        }  
#logout1 {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: 3%;
        padding: 2.5%;
        width: 30%;
    }
    #logoutIcon1 {
        background-image: url("../JunosImages/mob/back-arrow_normal_tab.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 14px;
        margin-top: 2%;
        width: 10px;
    }
    #logoutText1 {
        color: #fff;
        float: left;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin-left: 7%;
    }
```

Comment: The container #logout1 as a whole should float left, not the elements inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pulled right both buttons. Just replace `pull-right` class with `pull-left` in the second button and swap these buttons.

Also [don’t use ID selectors in CSS](http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/).

Answer (score 2):

are u use bootstrap so please check the below ans...
class="pull-left";

Answer (score 0):

i would do it like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .footer {
        background-color: #125e9a;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 5%;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }  

     .footer-links{
          display: block;
          float:left;
          margin-left: 3%;
          padding: 0.5%;
          width: 98px;
     }
     .arrow{
          background-color: green;
          height: 14px;
          margin-top: 2%;
          width: 10px;
     }
     .footer .button-text{
          color: #fff;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: 600;
          margin-left: 7%;
     }

     .footer-links-wrapper{
        width: 215px;
     }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="footer" class="footer">
        <div class="footer-links-wrapper">
            <span id="help" class="pull-left footer-links">
                 <span id="left-arrow" class="arrow left-arrow"> << </span>
                 <span id="help-text" class="button-text">
                                HELP
                 </span>
             </span>

            <span id="logout" class="pull-right footer-links">

                <span id="logout-text" class="button-text">
                                LOGOUT
                </span>
                <span id="right-arrow" class="arrow right-arrow"> >> </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

1. always better to write styles in classes and not by id
2. use "=" in attributes without spaces
3. name of classes and ids have to explain what you do (one way of comments)
4. in your code missing other styles, for look what you did in local browser